# On the growth of the Riemann zeta function on the critical line

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Is it true that

$$|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|< \frac{1}{4}+t^2$$ for all $t\geq 0$, where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function ?

It is known that the left hand-side is $O(t^{0.25})$, and on the the Lindelof Hypothesis, it is actually $O(t^\epsilon)$ for any positive $\epsilon$. But since these results are only valid for large $|t|$, thyey dont seem to answer my question.

**Note:** I have added abs value for The LHS of inequality because it is not clear if $\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)$ is always real number

Comment: In the paper: Hiary, Ghaith A. An explicit van der Corput estimate for ζ(1/2+it). Indag. Math. (N.S.) 27 (2016), no. 2, 524–533. It is proved that $|\zeta(1/2+it)|\le 0.63 t^{1/6}\log t$ for $t\ge 3$ and we have $|\zeta(1/2+it)|\le 1.461$ for $0\le t\le 3$. Of course the proof is more complicate than that in the answer of Carlo Beenakker.

Comment: You can find further useful bounds here: http://iml.univ-mrs.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art06.html

Answer (score 10):

The inequality at the top of page 99 in [Lectures on
The Riemann Zeta–Function](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr01.pdf) gives
$$|\zeta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it)|<9t^{1/2},\;\;t\geq 1.$$
To cover the whole the interval $t\geq 0$, just add $3/2$ to the right-hand-side of the inequality.

The inequality $|\zeta(\tfrac{1}{2}+it)|<\tfrac{1}{4}+t^2$ holds for $t> 0.8$.

Answer (score 1):

Visually,

[image]

where black dots are values of $\zeta\left(\frac12+it\right)$ and the red ones are at the distance $\frac14+t^2$ from the origin.